# Process string using Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, maze

I am in need of some guidance. I am not sure how to go about reading in the sample text file into an array of objects using Java Streams. Does stream provide a functionality to correctly output a position of the character from a string that it reads from the file?

I am reading a file using Java I/O and then passing the content as string to this function to create array of Squares....

Can this creation of Array of Objects be done using Java 8 Stream ? If so How please. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try something there? I hope you meant to tag [tag:java-stream] there instead of [tag:stream].

Comment: I would advise NOT doing this.  Your existing code will be faster AND much easier to understand than a solution that uses streams.

Comment: Would you please show us a couple lines of your input file?

Comment: @NomadMaker - it is implicit in the way he is reading it.  It consists of lines of characters with each line represent a row, and each character representing the `Square` at the corresponding column within the row.

Comment: @Stephon C Yes, I see how he is reading it. However, seeing the file shows if there is anything he's ignoring: header lines, comments, etc.

Comment: @naman,  added ty.

Comment: @NomadMaker - added the file ty and not ignoring anything.

Comment: Java-8-steams are one way of processing list data. In this case, I suspect that the basic for and while loops will do it in a more obvious way.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Since you only use Square in the array, why do you duplicate the row and column positions inside the object when they are already in the array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using java streams you could do something like this:

```
        AtomicInteger row = new AtomicInteger(-1);
        // count specific characters with this:
        AtomicInteger someCount = new AtomicInteger();
        try (Stream<String> stringStream = Files.lines(Paths.get("yourFile.txt"))) { // read all lines from file into a stream of strings

            // This Function makes an array of Square objects of each line
            Function<String, Square[]> mapper = (s) -> {
                AtomicInteger col = new AtomicInteger();
                row.incrementAndGet();
                return s.chars()
                        .mapToObj(i -> {
                            // increment counter if the char fulfills condition
                            if((char)i == 'M')
                                someCount.incrementAndGet();
                            return new Square(row.get(), col.getAndIncrement(), (char)i);
                        })
                        .toArray(i -> new Square[s.length()]);
            };

            // Now streaming all lines using the mapper function from above you can collect them into a List<Square[]> and convert this List into an Array of Square objects
            Square[][] squares = stringStream
                    .map(mapper)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Square[0][]);
        }
```

Answering your second question: If you have an array of Square[] and want to find the first Square with val == 'M' you could do this:

```
Optional<Square> optSquare = Stream.of(squares).flatMap(Stream::of).filter(s -> s.getVal() == 'M').findFirst();

// mySquare will be null if no Square was matching condition
Square mySquare = optSquare.orElse(null);
```

Comment: - If i have a additional check for a specific character in the loop, 

if( char(i,j) == 'M') someCount++; can i do using the same stream ?

Comment: @UserIkhar I added some code for the increment of a counter of special characters

Comment: As predicted, this code is much more complicated than the original version which used simple loops.  If you benchmark it (correctly!) I predict that this version will be substantially slower too.

Comment: @mexicomanni   - what if we have to return a an object from loop ? I have tried with IntStream but not getting it to work.. for (int i = 0 ; i < getHeight(); i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < getWidth(); j++) {
                Square s = getSquare(i, j);
                if (s.val() == 'M')
                    return s;
            }

Comment: @UserIkhar Where would you set the val of Square? - If you just want to find the first Square with character M you could map to `Square` objects and then use `filter(predicate)` with your condition and then get an `Optional<Square>` with `findFirst()`

Comment: @mexicomanni  Once the squares[][] are loaded from the file. i want to be able to get a specific square based on the value provided, so i can perform manipulation on that square.. how do I map the 2d array ?

Comment: @mexicomanni - that will preserve order, what If i have to convert back this squares into a textual format as it was before ?   I have method that tries to convert it back to textual format with \n inserted after every line to restore it

Comment: Why downvoting this answer? Wouldn't it be better to tell us all what, in your opinion, is wrong with the answer?

Comment: @mexicomanni -  i have upvoted but mines dont count as I am newbie here, someone else has downvoted it! As far as Im concerned it works fine! Would the following work to restore back to string format from Squares? 

Stream.of(squares).flatMap(Stream::of)
     .map(s -> s.getVal() == "M" ? result.append('X'): 
        s.getVal() == "N" ? result.append('S'):
         s.getVal() == "O" ? result.append('F'):
           s.getColumn() == getWidth()-1? result.append('\n'):
             result.append(' '));

Comment: @UserIkhar - I know, that you did not down vote. If the answer is usefull for you, you can accept the answer. - Concerning your question about restore it to a string: What exactly do you want to restore to a string? If you want to have a string representation of any Square you could override `toString()` in your Square class.

Comment: @mexicomanni - I need to generate different representation but back to the textual format, where currently i look through all elements within the 2D array compare  in two for loops and lot of if/else statements. what do i need to do for the above to work ?

Comment: @UserIkhar - I think the further work you need to do is out of the scope of this question. Maybe you could post another question where you explain more detailed what is your task. This way we keep this question more or less clear for other users.,,